# how do i generate waybill using third party API when click on place order button in magento?

Tags: magento-1.9, rest-api

how do i generate waybill using third party API when each order placed, for example if place an order by click on **place order** button i need to generate a waybill for this order. how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new module  app/etc/modules/Arunendra_Pratap.xml file is as follows.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Arunendra_Pratap>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
            <depends>
                <Mage_Checkout/>
                <Mage_Sales/>
                <Mage_CatalogInventory/>
            </depends>
        </Arunendra_Pratap>
    </modules>
</config>
```

Now create file on app/code/local/Arunendra/Pratap/etc/config.xml file is as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Arunendra_Pratap>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </Arunendra_Pratap>
    </modules>
<global>
    <models>
                <pratap>
                    <class>Arunendra_Pratap_Model</class>
                </pratap>
            </models>
        <events>

                <checkout_submit_all_after>
                    <observers>
                        <awesome_example>
                            <class>Arunendra_Pratap_Model_Observer</class>
                            <method>Waybill</method>
                        </awesome_example>
                    </observers>
                </checkout_submit_all_after>
            </events>
</global>
</config>
```

Lastlly create Observer file as follow

app/code/local/Arunendra/Pratap/Model/Observer.php

```
<?
class Arunendra_Pratap_Model_Observer {
    /**
     * This function is triggered by a Magento observer declared
     * in etc/config.xml
     *
     * @param Varien_Event_Observer $observer
     */
    public function Waybill($observer)
    {

      $order=$observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
        // Do whatever you need here 
    }
}
```

Comment: Below function is to use generate waybill using delhivery API how do i use this with your fuction                                                                       function new_way_bill()
{
    $token = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
    $waybill_url = 'https://test.delhivery.com/waybill/api/fetch/json/token='.$token.'&cl=name';  $result = file_get_contents($waybill_url); retutn $result;}

Comment: $waybill_url = 'https://test.delhivery.com/waybill/api/fetch/json/token=7ab6fc5d42832715aa83d46fe7ffb41f000afeee'&cl=GEECHOO';

Comment: Is this a shipping method ?

Comment: Yes. Delhivery shipping method.